# Angular doesn't respond to changing value of an input through jquery, only does if it's manually typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a text box that changes value based on mousewheel. (increments/decrements numbers in it)

I achieve this via jquery.

But Angular doesn't respond to the changes made via jquery.

```
<input ng-model='data'></input> {{data}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxw8N/

Only works if I manually enter the value.

Is there a way to have Angular respond to jquery changing the input value?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery if you use angular. In fact jquery just gets in the way of angular. If you must use jquery you need to trigger scope digest manually. If (!$scope.$digest) {$scope.$apply} 
If it happened outside of angular scope, it won't trigger angular watch.